# How can I arrange two tables in Quarto PDF in R, along with their caption and sub-captions?

Tags: r, knitr, quarto

I want to use Quarto to generate PDF document output. I want to arrange two tables, one below the other. My code is as follows:

YAML header

```
---
title: "Two Tables"
format: pdf
editor: visual
crossreference: true
---
```

Code to load packages required

```
#Load packages
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

After loading these packages, the actual code is as follows:

```
#| tbl-cap: Two tables
#| tbl-subcap: ["Head", "Tail"]
#| layout-nrows: 2
::: {#table1 caption="Table 1: First Table"}
kable(head(mtcars))
:::
::: {#table2 caption="Table 2: Second Table"}
kable(tail(mtcars))
:::
```

But I am getting error in this operation:

```
Quitting from lines 18-27 [unnamed-chunk-2] (Kable.qmd)
Error in `parse()`:
! <text>:1:1: unexpected ':::'
1: :::
```

And when I don't use the `:::` syntax, I get different error:
The code

```
#| tbl-cap: Two tables
#| tbl-subcap: ["Head", "Tail"]
#| layout-nrows: 2

kable(head(mtcars))
kable(tail(mtcars))
```

The error message

```
ERROR: 
compilation failed- error
Illegal parameter number in definition of \GetTitleStringResult.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.217 \caption{Head {#tbl-anonymous-9642553-1}}
                                               \tabularnewline
```

Of course, I know the workaround: keep the two tables in two different code chunks. But is there a way to generate two tables, with a master caption, and sub-caption for both the tables, and the two tables arranged one below the other?

Edit: my quarto version is 1.4.404 and knitr version is 1.44.

Answer (score 1):

Using quarto version 1.3.433, this code works for me:

````
---
title: "Two Tables"
format: pdf
---


```{r}
#| label: tbl-mtcars
#| tbl-cap: "Mtcars Data"
#| tbl-subcap: 
#|     - "Head"
#|     - "Tail"
#| layout-nrows: 2
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(mtcars))
kable(tail(mtcars))
```
````

[image]

Comment: My quarto version is 1.4.404.

Comment: And my answer does not work for you?

Comment: No, it is not working on my system.

Comment: you might want to file an issue on github then.